# Wavy Image on External Monitor, fixed by loggin in using only External Monitor

Tags: debian, drivers, monitors

I'm currently running Debian 12, and have tried Kali, Ubuntu and Fedora. In all these OSes, I have a wavy output to my external VGA monitor (Acer K192HQL) connected through a HDMI to VGA adapter.

A have found a fix to this problem, but would like to know what I can do to make it go away forever. Maybe a script or something.

The Fix:

1. Lock/Log out of profile
2. Close laptop lid
3. Wake and sign in using an external keyboard
4. Open laptop lid

It has to be done in that particular way otherwise it will not work. I do suspect some driver issue, as the monitor works perfectly without any fuss on windows.

Comment: That sounds like a hardware issue with your monitor (it's not properly synchronizing on the first try) and not something that software (i.e., Linux) could solve. You could try to turn off the HDMI output, wait shortly, and turn it back on. But that sounds... Sketchy. You sure are using the right resolution and a low frame rate, right?